# Oracle SQL to get count of first occurrences of a row in the full data set filtered by date?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID       eventType     date
--------------------------------
1        foo           2 March 2013
2        foo           3 March 2013
3        bar           3 March 2013
4        foo           5 March 2013
5        foo           6 March 2013
6        bar           7 March 2013
7        baz           8 March 2013
```

I can easily get the unique list of `eventTypes` from this list.  However, how do I query the count of which `eventTypes` first appeared BETWEEN `startDate` and `endDate`.  I want to be able to have a date range from 7 March 2013 - 10 March 2013 and get a count returned of 1 since `baz` value was a newly occurring `eventType` during the date range.  On the other hand, a date range of 5 March 2013 - 7 March 2013 would return a count of 0 since no newly occurring `eventTypes` appeared in that range.

Comment: How can you tell that there were no new events between mar 5 and 7? Which even in your example is new and which is old? I see 2-foo and 1-bar within those dates. If foo is old then bar should be new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just look at using the `MIN` aggregate function to find the earliest occurrence of the event type before the end date of the query. Then I would see if any events had their earliest event after the start date of the range.

```
SELECT event_type, date_value
from (
  SELECT event_type, min(date_value) as date_value
  from your_table
  where date_value <= date '2013-03-10'
  group by event_type
)
where date_value >= date '2013-03-07'
```

Comment: As written, this one worked correctly on my dataset.  For some reason the previous answers didn't always work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you.  Basically join the table against itself:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.EventType)
FROM YourTable T
   LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.eventType = T2.eventType AND T2.dateField < to_date('2013-03-07','yyyy-mm-dd')
WHERE T.DateField BETWEEN to_date('2013-03-07','yyyy-mm-dd') 
  AND to_date('2013-03-10','yyyy-mm-dd')
       AND T2.Id IS NULL
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bfb1/13).

-- EDIT

As @JoachimIsaksson correctly pointed out, you can just as easily (and probably preferably), change the `LEFT JOIN` to:

```
   LEFT JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.eventType = T2.eventType AND T2.dateField < T.dateField
```

Good luck.

Comment: Changing the start date to `2013-03-03` returns 3. Afaict it should return 2...?

Comment: Good point -- add DISTINCT -- editing now -- thanks @JoachimIsaksson!

Comment: ...or change the second condition of the `LEFT JOIN` to `AND T2.dateField < T.dateField`. +1 either way :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT eventType)
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE
    date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
        WHERE T1.eventType = T2.eventType AND T2.date < :startDate
    )
```

In plain English:

- Exclude all rows whose `eventType` already exists before the given date.
- And then just count the distinct occurrences of what's left in the given date range.

Another way to express the same would be using MINUS:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT eventType
  FROM your_table
  WHERE date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
  MINUS
  SELECT eventType
  FROM your_table
  WHERE date < :startDate
);
```

Note: COUNT(DISTINCT) isn't required in this case because MINUS implies DISTINCT, i.e. the left side of MINUS will return only unique entries.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your data and question but I think you may use analytic functions to partition your data by dates between/range_between and event type. Then you'd have rownum() or rank()/dense_rank() in your partitions which would be your sequence. The lowest seq. maybe your answer.